# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 - Icons not displaying on projected screen

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, projector

I recently had to teach the basics of web design to my classmates in college (because my teacher asked me to), and I showed them few examples and practical stuff on my laptop. But when I connected my laptop to the projector, I noticed that most of the icons on my desktop weren't displaying on the projector screen. My desktop layout is shown below:

[image: My desktop layout]

The folder icons on the left appear, but all the icons on the right aren't displaying on the projector screen. I even tried cycling between display modes. But nothing worked. This isn't something important, but I want to know why this is happening. And if there's a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your display settings to "mirror" the outputs.

- Bring up your dash screen and type Displays.
- Click the Displays icon
- From there, you need to select the Mirroring option. Go through the settings carefully. It should give you "Mirror Outputs" or "Displays" or something like that. I am not a GNOME user so I do not recall the exact wording.

This way, what you see on your screen will be mirrored on the "extended" display - whatever that might be - a projector, an LCD screen, a video switcher etc.

Pay close attention to the "Primary" output option. You do **not** want to set the primary output to be the projector / LCD etc.

**UPDATE**: Here is a screenshot that I downloaded and modified - I have highlighted the mirroring option. Original screenshot can be obtained [here](https://blogs.gnome.org/thos/files/2013/09/screenshot-2.png).

To get to this screen, you may need to click on the "Arrange Combined Displays" button.

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said. But I can't seem to find a Mirror Output option. Is it because I haven't connected to another display now?

Comment: That's correct, the secondary display must be connected first.